# Epub Reader Usage using Monocle

Tags: epub, monocle

I need one conformation about using epub reader.how to give input as .epub file in monocle epub reader.I saw more samples in monocle github. But cannot identify which one will works.

I need to know about Monocle Epub reader below specifications :

```
 1. I have one .epub file

 2.how to read .epub using monocle epub reader
```

i didn't get any solutions reading that.I saw monocle epub related link is :

https://github.com/joseph/Monocle#future-directions

I tries to below code :

```
<head>
  <!-- Include the Monocle library and styles -->
  <script src="scripts/monocore.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/monocore.css" />
  <style>
    #reader { width: 300px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid #000; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- The reader element, with all content to paginate inside it -->
  <div id="reader">
    <h1>Hello world.</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- Instantiate the reader when the containing element has loaded -->
  <script>Monocle.Reader('reader');</script>
</body>
```

But can't get any idea about to give input file as epub file.

So can you please suggest me how to read .epub file using monocle epub redaer.It is very imaportant for me.or Is there any apis for epub readers for ios and android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Please see once my post.How i can read .epub file using monocle?.Can you please suggest me or provide example code.@Drop

Comment: did you acheive it ? i am having the same requirement

Answer (score 0):

Please try following step.

1. Convert .epub to zip file
2. Extract .zip file.
3. Load extracted content by using Monocle.